# Split by [char] but not by [char]{2} via regex

Tags: php, regex, split

I need do it, basically:

```
Parameter    | Expected Result (array)
a            | [a]
a_b          | [a, b]
a_b_c        | [a, b, c]
a__b         | [a_b] <-- note that the double underline be unique
a_b__c       | [a, b_c]
```

I know how I do it with the methods `explode` and `str_replace` and using a `foreach` to converts `__` to `_`. Basically this:

```
<?php

    $parameter = 'a_b__c';

    $expected = str_replace( '__', "\0", $parameter ); # "a_b\0c"
    $expected = explode( '_', $expected );             # ["a", "b\0c"]

    foreach ( $expected as &$item )
        $item = str_replace( "\0", '_', $item );

    # ["a", "b_c"]

?>
```

But I guess that with `preg_*` it can be more fast. Or am I wrong?

Well, I accept any better suggestion. :)

**Help note**: the `$parameter` will be ever a PHP identifier (generally a class identifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following approach using [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$result = preg_split("/(?<!_)_(?!_)/", $parameter);
```

`?<!` and `?!` are zero-width negative [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertions.

Comment: @David Rodrigues Just saw that you also want ' __' => '_'. Thinking about that one...

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to split and replace in a single regex operation. 
Let us say you have input a_b__c. In the first step you can split using the expression (same as what Howard gave)
`$result = preg_split('/(?<!_)_(?!_)/', $subject);` which would give you `[a, b__c]`
Now you can iterate on each of the entry in the array and do the replace using  
 `$result = preg_replace('/_(?=_)/', '', $subject);` which would help you 
replace `b__c` with `b_c`.